# Is it possible to convert an SSL certificate from a .key file to a .pfx?

Tags: ssl-certificate, pfx

is there a way to convert from a .key file to a .pfx file?
thank you.

EDIT: I only have the .key file but my hosting provider says that I could convert it to .pfx with just that file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To check if your .key file has everything you need:

```
#check if file contains a valid certificate:
openssl x509 -text -in file.key
```

It should print out certificate details. If it prints an error including the text  "unable to load certificate", then your file is not sufficient.

```
#check if file contains a valid key:
openssl rsa -text -in file.key
openssl dsa -text -in file.key
```

One of the above commands should print out valid key details. The other will give an error with the text "expecting an rsa key" or "expecting a dsa key".

If the error text says "bad decrypt", you have provided an invalid passphrase, or the file is damaged.

If the error text says "Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY", then your file is not sufficient.

If you got a key, and one certificate which matches the key (and optionally some other certificates), then you have enough to convert the file to a pfx. Then, as ISW said, it's just a matter of

```
#convert file containing key and certificate(s) to PKCS#12 pfx file.
openssl pkcs12 -export -out file.pfx -in file.key
```

and you're done.

Comment: @jlp - No, OpenSSL is not a part of Windows, it is a standalone software package (http://www.openssl.org/), available also for Windows (http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)

Comment: If the first command fails, you can do this: open your .key and .spc in notepad, copy the whole content of both files and create a new one called `newfile.key`. Then run again the `openssl x509 -text -in newfile.key` command and it should work. Then you can convert the `newfile.key` to .pfx using `openssl pkcs12 -export -out newfile.pfx -in newfile.key`

Comment: @dacap: Thanks - yes, if you have the key and certificate in separate files you can combine them as you describe. You can also use the method @fig suggested below, [using `-inkey` for the key file, and `-in` for the certificate (.spc) file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/553165/43452)...

Comment: ... Why Microsoft doesn't provide the function to convert .key to .pvk in pvk2pfx or signtool?

Answer (score 18):

You could try this
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Comment: Hi Dave, the thing is that I only have a .key file, no .crt file. Is it possible that the .key contains the certificate?

Comment: My hosting provider insists that this is the format they use and that in it is contained the certificate.

Comment: Years later... after scouring SO and going through at least a dozen similar questions and countless answers, this answer is EXACTLY what I needed to create a PFX (PKCS12) from a certificate, private key in a .KEY file, and a series of root/intermediate trust authorities.  THANKS!

Comment: argh, sharing certificate's private key is not the best way to do it secure

Comment: user65663, you are the best.

Comment: .pfx by nature requires public & private key. So you need to provide the public key to form the .pfx. For me, I use `openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.cer` and it works. After that just import the private key from .pfx into .jks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenSSL Command-Line HOWTO](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-pkcs12) it should work using

```
# export mycert.key as PKCS#12 file mycert.pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycert.pfx -in mycert.key -name "My Certificate"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your .key file to .pvk using the tool http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_347.asp and then use the instructions on GoDaddy to combine both .scp and .pvk into a .pfk. Just make sure you use a password when generating the .pvk file.