# using OpenSSL to create .pfx file

Tags: openssl, pfx, keytool

I've been offered some commands to create a .pfx file using OpenSSL.  For the most part, my partner gathered this information from: [Is it possible to convert an SSL certificate from a .key file to a .pfx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553149/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-key-file-to-a-pfx)

I have the following files:

1. 2010certificate.cer
2. 2010cert_and_key.pem
3. private_verisign10to11.key

I have tried to generate with both:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out s2010-1.pfx -inkey private_verisign10to11.key -in 2010cert_and_key.pem -certfile 2010certificate.cer
and
openssl pkcs12 -export -out s2010-1.pfx -inkey private_verisign10to11.key -in 2010certificate.cer -certfile 2010cert_and_key.pem
```

No errors are thrown in this situation, but when I try to view or import the generated file s2010-1.pfx, Protecle says it can't open it. Keytool says:

```
keytool -import -file s2010-1.pfx x -keystore cacerts -alias fqdn -storepass <.pfx's pass word>
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

I am assuming the problem is with the .pfx generation, but I don't really know how to test it until the keytool command.  Any suggestions on what to do from here would be great.

Comment: Java can treat a PKCS12 _as_ a keystore, but [before 8u60 (in 2015 well after this Q)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u60-relnotes-2620227.html) you had to specify it: `keytool -list -keystore whatever.pfx -storetype pkcs12`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [TinyCA](http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/) to open each of your 3 files, because they can be something else that what their extension says, specially the .pem ones. Then use TinyCA to export the keys ; There is a message window displaying both the openssl command and the output of said command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `keytool -importcert` (`-import` in Java < 1.6) only support importing x509 certificates.

**To import a PKCS12 (sometimes delivered in a .pfx file) into a Java .jks file, including `cacerts`:**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass <mysecret> -destkeystore cacerts -deststoretype JKS  -deststorepass changeit
```