# How can I create PFX certificate signed by some CA from scratch?

Tags: ssl, openssl, pfx, pkcs#12

I want to generate certificate for my domain locally and then sign it, for example, by getaCert.com service.
But I get an error at the end.

Below are steps:

- Create config for OpenSSL openssl.cnf based on http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl.conf
- Create private key my.key and certificate request my.csr

  openssl req -new -nodes -keyout my.key -out my.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -config openssl.cnf
- Submit my.csr to http://www.getacert.com/signacert.html and download signed public certificate my.cer and CA certificate getacert.cer
- Try create PFX

  openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.cer -inkey my.key -out gd.p12 -certfile getacert.cer

Error occurs: No certificate matches private key

Why? And what am I doing wrong?

Here are similar question but without any reasonable answer

[using OpenSSL to create .pfx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868989/using-openssl-to-create-pfx-file)

[Is it possible to convert an SSL certificate from a .key file to a .pfx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553149/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-key-file-to-a-pfx)