# Joining GoDaddy-issued .spc and .key files into a complete .pfx / .cer certificate

Tags: certificate, key, code-signing, pfx, spc

I have a GoDaddy-issued code signing certificate in a `.spc` file. Also, I have a private key in `.key` file. The code signing has been issued some 13 months ago, then it expired and was renewed with GoDaddy. During the renewal process no private key was requested and just a new `.spc` file was issues.

Now I'm facing the problem of joining the original private key file with the issues certificate to form a `.pfx` (or `.cer`?) file suitable for installation into the Windows certificate store.

The command I'm trying is:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -inkey my.key -in my.spc -out my.pfx -export
```

However, I'm getting an error message that reads *“No certificate matches private key”*.

I've followed [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553149/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-key-file-to-a-pfx/660474#660474) to verify the `.key` file is a valid private key. However, when I try to verify that `.spc` is a valid certificate, I just get

```
unable to load certificate 
5436:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

What's the correct way of producing an `.pfx` file from my inputs? I'm using OpenSSL 0.9.8k.

Comment: Are you using IE8? Godaddy code signing script does not work with IE8. use firefox

Comment: No. I'm using Chrome 9 and FireFox 9. Nevertheless I can't see any connection between IE8 and my problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the end I managed to figure out a procedure that works. Here are the steps to generate a new PFX and CER code signing certificate from SPC and KEY files:

1. Obtain your new `CodeSign.spc` certificate from GoDaddy.
2. Export a PEM-formatted private key from the expired PFX:

   ```
   openssl.exe pkcs12 -in CodeSign.pfx -nocerts -out CodeSign.pem
   ```
3. Convert the PEM-formatted private key into the PVK format:

   ```
   pvk.exe -in CodeSign.pem -topvk -strong -out CodeSign.pvk
   ```
4. Combine the PVK and SPC into PFX:

   ```
   pvk2pfx.exe -pvk CodeSign.pvk -pi <passphrase> -spc CodeSign.spc -pfx CodeSign.pfx -po <passphrase> -f
   ```
5. Import the resulting PFX file into Windows certificate store. Remember to make it exportable.
6. Export it from the certificate store into the binary CER format as `CodeSign.cer`.
7. Optionally delete the certificate from the Windows certificate store.

In case you are renewing your certificate periodically you can store the PVK file and skip steps (2) and (3).

**UPDATE:** In case you happen to have the certificate in CRT instead of SPC format, do the following to covert it into SPC:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile CodeSign.crt -outform DER -out CodeSign.spc
```

Sources:

- http://www.tech-pro.net/export-to-pvk-spc.html
- http://ellisweb.net/2008/08/signing-code-using-pvk-and-spc-files/
- http://www.drh-consultancy.demon.co.uk/
- https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html
- http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/solved-convert-signing-certificate-crt-to-spc/

The tools you will need:

- [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)
- [`pvk.exe`](http://www.drh-consultancy.demon.co.uk/pvk.html) — see the download link at the bottom of that page (original location may not be accessible; in such a case see [this article](http://www.tech-pro.net/export-to-pvk-spc.html) with a link to a mirror site or another direct download [link here](http://www.digi-sign.com/downloads/software/PVK.zip))
- [`pvk2pfx.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) — part of Microsoft SDKs, installs with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: This answer does not include information about how to work with the .key file as mentioned in the original question. In the above process, did you not need to use the .key file?

Comment: No, as mentioned in my answer, I had to use the `pfx` file to export the private key into the PEM format. I haven't used the `key` file ever since; always follow the abovementioned steps every year when renewing our code signing certificate.

Comment: Understood - this is assuming that there is an original pfx (expired) to start with, correct? In my case, I do not have a PFX - thats what I'm trying to get to. I basically picked up your instructions at `pvk.exe -in CodeSign.pem -topvk -strong -out CodeSign.pvk` but in my case `CodeSign.pem` was `CodeSign.key` (which is as I understand just a PEM formatted private key, that could just as easily be named `CodeSign.pem` as well). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I had the original (expired) PFX. I have a practice of having all such important files stored in a Subversion repository, so we don't loose them (including the history). All the private keys being encrypted ensures this is secure, too. On the other hand, we are avoiding importing complete public/private pairs into Windows' certificate store with exportable private keys, so it's quite important to keep the PFX separately.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I get the following:
`ERROR: Cannot find certificates that match the key.
(Error Code = 0x80070490).`

Comment: Was able to complete the instructions with the new key file (using @Ryan's method, of substituting the .pem for the .key file) -- but the certificate isn't actually working to create strong name assemblies it says "Failed to extract public key from key pair -- keyset does not exist" (the old .pfx file worked fine for this).

Comment: Did you specify the correct keyset name? Did you run cmd as administrator?

Comment: Ondrej Tucny's answer worked for me, with one modification: I needed to add the "-nodes" parameter to the first step (openssl.exe). To convert to P12, use Firefox: Tools, Options, Advanced, Certificates, View Certificates, Import PFX, Backup to P12.

Comment: Fantastic! The pvk.exe is not available at the website of drh-consultancy anymore but you find a mirror of the file at http://www.tech-pro.net/export-to-pvk-spc.html

Comment: @StefanWanitzek Thanks for pointing that out. Updated in the answer.

Comment: The mirror of pvk.exe was blocked at work as "containing malware". I was able to use Nikita Krasnov's answer and avoid the need of any additional software other than OpenSSL.

Answer (score 14):

I had the similar issue and I spent at least few hours searching around for a solution. GoDaddy provided me with .spc and .pem file and I couldn't create .pfx file out if it using OpenSSL. Finally, I imported .spc file within my local computer using MMC. Once the certificate was imported in my local machine, I noticed that it brought in GoDaddy's chain file along with the Code Sign Cert file itself. [MMC View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsl1N.png)

Now, select both files and right click to export as .pfx file. Supply a password to protect the file and you're done. By far, this is the simplest and straight forward solution. Hope this post helps many people.

Comment: THANK YOU! This solved my problem as well after hours of searching. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 11):

You can create PFX with openssl only.

1. Export a PEM-formatted private key from the expired PFX:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in CodeSign.pfx -nocerts -out CodeSign.pem
   ```
2. Create PFX

   ```
   openssl pkcs7 -in CodeSign.spc -inform der -print_certs | openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey CodeSign.pem -out CodeSign.pfx
   ```

Comment: I kept trying these steps via a WSL command-line and it would not work (the second step would fail, complaining about the private key). I eventually realized that you MUST provide a PEM pass phrase for the first step. This is in addition to any import password you may have had on the original PFX file.

Answer (score 3):

The current answer post was extremely helpful to me in the final steps of moving from an expired certificate file (.pfx or .p12) to a new one with GoDaddy, but I found it lacking information on the initial steps of how to generate a certificate signing request (CSR) from my original certificate file.

For anyone else looking for similar information, here is what I ended up using...

Get the private key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certs-and-key.p12 -out privateKey.key
```

Get the certificatate:

**Beware: This can give you the CA cert**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certs-and-key.p12 -out certificate.crt -nokeys
```

**Better: Use this command to print only the client cert**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in MacCossLabUW.p12 -clcerts
```

Then copy the output between:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Save it to a file named certificate.crt

Now check that the private key and certificate match with the commands:

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5
```

Then generate a new CSR:

```
openssl x509 -x509toreq -in certificate.crt -out CSR.csr -signkey privateKey.key
```

Use the CSR to Re-Key the certificate.

Download the GoDaddy software publishing certificate (.spc) file.

Verify that the generated certificate matches the request private key:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in certificate.spc -print_certs
```

Then copy the output between for your certificate (Note: the output will also contain CA certs):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Save to a file named certificate-new.crt

And run the command:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate-new.crt | openssl md5
```

The output should match the previous call used with the private key and request certificate.

To finish the process, follow the steps outlined in the answer with pvk2pfx.

I also found the schematic diagram in this post quite helpful:

[PVK2PFX Error 0x80070490 - Cannot find certificates that match the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071160/pvk2pfx-error-0x80070490-cannot-find-certificates-that-match-the-key)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for an answer on how to do this, I just spent a day figuring this out and had to do a mix of things listed in this post. If you are using git-bash on windows, I had to add `winpty` to the beginning of all calls using openssl or else it would get stuck in the void. The pseudo steps were as follows:

1. Generate a private key and CSR using openssl

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out my.csr
```

2. Generate a PVK using the private key with openssl

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -outform PVK -pvk-strong -out codesign.pvk
```

3. Use the CSR in the generation of the code sign certificate on Godaddy
4. Download the Zip from Godaddy and extract the SPC file (as mentioned by OP)
5. Use pvk2pfx to combine the PVK and the SPC file into a code sign certificate. This was included in the same SDK (and directory) as signtool itself:

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk codesign.pvk -spc SPC_FILEPATH_HERE -pfx codesign.pfx -pi PVK_PASSWORD -po PFX_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score -1):

If you generated your certificate request from IIS (I did this on IIS on windows 2012 Server) follow these steps on the server/pc where you generated the request
- Open IIS
- Click on the top level node (Server node)
- Open the Server Certificates settings
- Click on "Complete certificate request" under actions on the right
- Import your spc file to the server.

From here you can then export to a PFX file

Comment: The question is about a *code signing* certificate. Your answer is unfortunately irrelevant.