# PVK2PFX Error 0x80070490 - Cannot find certificates that match the key

Tags: code-signing, signtool

We got our new certificate (*.cer) file from Thawte, and i went through our standard procedures to allow it for use with code signing.

If i use our old (working) certificate:

1. Convert certificate (*.cer) into Software Publishing Certificate (*.spc)

   ```
   >Cert2Spc.exe Avatar.cer Avatar.spc
   Succeeded
   ```
2. Combine our private key file (*.pvk) with the SPC into a PFX:

   ```
   >pvk2pfx.exe -pvk Avatar.pvk -spc Avatar.spc -pfx Avatar.pfx -f
   ```

   *prompts for private key file password, enter it, click OK*

   [image]

And we're good to go; ready to use `signtool`.

---

We now have our **new** certificate, and i follow the same procedure:

1. Convert certificate (*.cer) into Software Publishing Certificate (*.spc)

   ```
   >Cert2Spc.exe Avatar.cer Avatar.spc
   Succeeded
   ```
2. Combine our private key file (*.pvk) with the SPC into a PFX:

   ```
   >pvk2pfx.exe -pvk Avatar.pvk -spc Avatar.spc -pfx Avatar.pfx -f
   ```

   *prompts for private key file password, enter it, click OK*

   [image]

   ```
   ERROR: Cannot find certificates that match the key.
   (Error Code = 0x80070490).
   ```

What's going wrong?

---

Notes:

- we've used the same private key file (*.pvk) for a decade
- this year Thawte gave us a **2-year** certificate; rather than the usual 1-year
- this year Thawte changed their signing certificate from **`Thawte Code Signing CA`** to **`Thawte Code Signing CA - G2`**
- Google says that *nobody* has ever gotten the error **Cannot find certificates to match the key.**
- The Windows SDK only contains two references to the error code `0x80070490`:

  - Visual Foxpro for Windows header file (`vfwmsgs.h`):

    ```
    //
    // MessageId: E_PROP_ID_UNSUPPORTED
    //
    // MessageText:
    //
    // The specified property ID is not supported for the specified property set.%0
    //
    #define E_PROP_ID_UNSUPPORTED            ((HRESULT)0x80070490L)
    ```

    Which is almost certainly a red herring; Foxpro?
  - commented out code in the RSS screensaver sample (`RssItem.cs`)

    ```
    // "Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"
    ```

    Also almost certainly a red-herring; XML?
- decimal version of `0x80070490` is `-2147023728`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that this year we were given a new private key.

Well, you're not *given* a private key, the certificate+key is fetched through the browser and stored in a certificate store. From there we can **export** a `.PFX` (A `pfx` contains a certificate and a private key).

With this PFX exported from the browser's certificate store, we can use it directly to sign code with `signtool`.

**Note**: We were actually gluttons for punishment, and went through steps:

```
+--[.pfx]---+     +--[.cer]---+     +--[.spc]---+           +--[.pfx]---+
|Certificate|====>|Certificate|====>|Software   |=========> |Certificate|
|    +      |     +-----------+     |Publishing |           |     +     |
|Private Key|==+       +            |Certificate|   +=====> |Private Key|
+-----------+  |                    +-----------+   |       +-----------+
               |                                    | 
               |                                    |
               |  +--[.pem]---+     +--[.pvk]---+   |
               +=>|Private Key| ==> |Private Key|===+
                  +-----------+     +-----------+
```

But all that route gave us was a private key file (`*.pvk`) that wasn't protected with a password; so `signtool` could run without user interaction.

But the answer to this question was: **The private key doesn't match the certificate.**