# Joining an SSL .crt certificate with a private key for use with WCF's Net.Tcp binding

Tags: wcf, ssl, net.tcp

I have a GoDaddy-issued SSL certificate in the `.crt` format. Also I have the previous expired certificate in the `.pfx` format which includes a private key.

Now I'm facing the problem of joining the original private key with the issued certificate to form a `.pfx` file suitable for installation into the Windows certificate store.

I followed steps that I used successfuly in a similar situation for producing a code signing certificate (documented in [this Q/A pair on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4682642/245183)). The resulting certificate works for HTTPS, **but not for WCF's Net.Tcp endpoints**. When such endpoint is used, it fails to initialize due to the following error:

> ArgumentException: It is likely that certificate 'CN=domain.com, O="Company", L=Abc, S=Abc, C=XY' may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for detail.

[Some sources](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/35be5be4-0c37-4a4d-8bad-7b30fcd9383c/atypical-problem-with-updating-ssl-certificate-for-existing-wcf-service-renders-service-inoperable) claim that it's necessary to use `www.domain.com` instead of `domain.com`. While this *can* be the issue in some cases, it proved not to be the root cause in my case.

What can be the root cause of this problem and how to get it fixed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is the certificate created from a `.spc` as an intermediary format, as resulting from following the steps [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5421465/245183), leads to loss of the `KeyExchange` flag.

The correct way to join the `.crt` with a private key is to use a private key in the `.pem` format, like this:

1. Obtain your new `Ssl.crt` certificate from GoDaddy.
2. Export a PEM-formatted private key from the expired PFX:

   ```
   openssl.exe pkcs12 -in ExpiredSslCert.pfx -nocerts -out SslPrivateKey.pem
   ```
3. Combine the CRT and PEM into PFX:

   ```
   openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in SslCert.crt -inkey SslPrivateKey.pem -out FullCert.pfx
   ```

The resulting `.pfx` now *has* the `KeyExchange` flag and works for WCF Net.Tcp bindings.